# Strict factor of a dynamical system with the same entropy

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy

Say that a factor of an invertible measure-preserving transformation $T$ is *strict* if it is not isomorphic to $T$. Does there exist an invertibe *mpt* $T$ such that $0 < h(T) < \infty$ and admitting a strict factor with entropy $h(T)$ ?

Comment: Why don't you take a product of measure-preserving transformations, with one of them having zero entropy (even topological)?

Comment: @JohnB: Because I don't see what you mean :-). I don't have a great knowledge in ergodic theory. I would be glad if you detailed your idea.

Comment: Sorry. Take two transformations $S$ and $T$, say preserving measures $\mu$ and $\nu$. Then $\mu\times\nu$ is invariant under $S\times T$. If $h(S)=0$ (topological entropy), then $h_{\mu\times\nu}(S\times T)=h_\nu(T)$ and clearly $S\times T$ and $T$ can be made nonisomorphic (the measure is nonzero, only the entropy is zero).

Comment: Sinai's theorem says that every mpt has a factor isomorphic to a Bernoulli shift with equal entropy.

Comment: @JohnB Can I take for instance a rotation for $S$ ? Then I take $T$ Bernoulli and I claim that $S \times T$ is not Bernoulli because it has a factor with zero entropy ? (I don't see why you use topological entropy by the way).

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Indeed, right. Thank you for recalling this theorem. But I would prefer an explicit example.

Comment: Right. I only mentioned topological entropy to note that we can have more examples by taking any invariant measure of the first map. Of course, Anthony is right about Sinai's work (perhaps I mention that although people usually refer to his 1964 paper, the result was announced in 1962).

Comment: As another example besides the above, take a direct sum of a transformation $T$ ($0<h(T)<\infty$) with itself and its natural factor to $T$. The probability weight of the two components could be chosen arbitrarily but non-trivially.

Comment: ... I forgot: you can choose $T$ to be ergodic to be sure it is not isomorphic to the direct sum.

Comment: On a second thought, my example is simply a special case of @JohnB's example, with $S$ being the identity map on $\{0,1\}$, and with an arbitrary nontrivial measure on $\{0,1\}$.